# Prompt For User Input Within A Function/Piped If Statement - Bash

Tags: bash, if-statement, pipe

Is it possible to prompt for user input when calling a function in bash?

Take this for example:

```
#!/bin/bash
test1(){

echo "Do you wish to install this program?"
select yn in "Yes" "No"; do
    case $yn in
        Yes ) make install; break;;
        No ) exit;;
    esac
done

}

pip list 2>/dev/null | if grep httplib2; then echo 2>/dev/null; else test1; fi
```

Disregard the fact I'm checking for httplib2 because I know that works fine if you else echo "Test". I've tried this with examples from stackoverflow and tldp, so I'm kind of confused now.

Can you not catch user input from a piped if statement?

Just tested with

```
pip list 2>/dev/null | if grep httplib2; then 
echo 2>/dev/null; 
else
echo "Type the year that you want to check (4 digits), followed by [ENTER]:"
read year
echo $year
fi
```

as well and had the same effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `test1` is in a pipeline but you need input from the terminal, use:

```
test1 </dev/tty
```

For example:

```
pip list 2>/dev/null | if grep httplib2; then echo 2>/dev/null; else test1 </dev/tty; fi
```

`test1` gets its input from stdin.  If you want to interact with it, its stdin must come from the terminal, `/dev/tty`, not from the pipeline.

An alternate method is to capture the handle for stdin before the pipeline starts.  For example:

```
exec 3<&0; echo http | test1 <&3; exec 3<&-
```

Or,

```
exec 3<&0
pip list 2>/dev/null | if grep httplib2; then echo 2>/dev/null; else test1 <&3; fi
exec 3<&-
```

Comment: If i use `exec 3<&0; echo http | test1 <&3` i get a broken pipe.

Comment: I thought the "if grep" got input from stdout and then the rest of the statement is just whether it was true or false?

Comment: @Revolt  That seems reasonable at first but the `if-then-else` construct is a _compound command_.  If stdin to the compound command is redirected, then, unless we explicitly change it, every statement within the compound command sees the redirected stdin.

Comment: @User112638726 "broken pipe" means that `test1` finished before `echo`.  In this case, it is a harmless message.

Comment: Interesting. So test1 was taking 'pip list' as an argument?

Comment: @Revolt To be more precise, when `test1` starts, it asks the `pip list` process for input.  Since the `pip list` process had already sent everything it had to `grep`, there was nothing left.   When the `select` statement in `test1` is told there is no input available, it quits.